# ASUS RP-AC51 UART doesn't work with any common baud rate

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

I have an [ASUS RP-AC51](https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Range-Extenders-/All-series/RP-AC51/). It doesn't broadcast any WiFi network when powered on, the management interface cannot be accessed over Ethernet, and the reset button seemingly does nothing.

I decided to try and get a shell on the device with UART. I'm following the instructions from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmZuKA-Rst0). [Here are photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVekQ.jpg) of my setup.

I use `screen` on the Pi to connect to the device:

```
pi@desk:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b95:772a ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772A Fast Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pi@desk:~ $ ls /dev | grep USB
ttyUSB0
pi@desk:~ $ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 300
```

I tried every single one of the common baud rates [listed in the video](https://youtu.be/ZmZuKA-Rst0?t=585). I never got any readable text. As an example, here's a snippet of what I get at 115200:

```
E�I�L)rNS:9
            4�"�*.W PFd���QN'S�Jj
PS� ��3Z�Y L    rr$j             �HR
                    -B����Y":j
                              0�VH. ��)j
                                        ath_!�J��+,W+�5��e��)�BHL��*W   "2J���WHa�5幮e�VVՕ�k�'�,յ�M"�J l9
          ��R��p@ ₂����RT� Plk  B��+E |         �6      ��2FJ!U�څ(es�'B�1       �L      ��L   ��1S�1` R�AU1b��J��
                  j
PS:��              ARU*R
```

Does anyone know what baud rate I should be using? Or am I doing something else wrong?

(I don't have an oscilloscope.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at another [device](https://openwrt.org/toh/asus/rp-n53) of the same family seems you need this configuration for the UART interface:

- baud rate: 57600
- data bit: 8
- parity: N
- stop bit: 1

`57600/8-N-1` (in short notation).

Comment: I set this configuration with `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 -parenb -cstopb`, then used `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 57600` to connect. Still got unreadable output.

Comment: You double-checked if RX and TX are in the right place? BTW you can configure all the parameters directly from Screen itself :)

Comment: Yes, triple-checked even. Maybe it's just bricked or something.

Comment: Did you try changing the adapter? 
You properly placed GND (adapter) ->GND(board)?

Comment: Yes, the ground pins are connected (as you can see in photos 2 and 3). This is the only adapter I have. It's brand new.

Comment: Did you try to connect the adapter to a PC without an HUB directly? (the I think I exhausted ideas for the moment)

Comment: there is the possibility, that the signal is inverted.
What I like to do in such situations is using a specail terminal sw (like hterm on windows) which lets me display the data in hex and binary. That way I see if I get long rows of ones and zeros. If that's the case, i can start to goess the correct datarate. But first: measure the voltage on the line when there is no data transmitted.